# Error using Vim substitute method

Tags: vim

I am using the `substitute()` method to script Vim so that code folds look different.

Code in `~/.vimrc` is as follows:

```
function! FoldText()
  let width = winwidth(0) - &foldcolumn - (&number ? 4 : 0)
  let first_line = getline(v:foldstart) . " ..."
  let edited_line = subsitute(first_line, "{ \.\.\.", "{ ... }", "")
  let expansion_string = repeat(" ", width)
  return edited_line . expansion_string
endfunction
set foldtext=FoldText()
```

The problem is that this doesn’t work, I just get this for each fold:

```
0-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I take out the `edited_line` and return `first_line . expansion_text` the first part works:

```
class Whatever { ...
```

But for purely aesthetic reasons I’d like folds which start with a brace to show the brace like so:

```
class Whatever { ... }
```

I’ve not used VimScript much, and this is mostly pinched from [this site](http://www.gregsexton.org/2011/03/improving-the-text-displayed-in-a-fold/), so I expect I’m missing something basic. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have that typo (`subsitute`) also in the original?!

Comment: Well dag-nammit :) Well spotted, that’s the problem right there!

Comment: The stumbling block is that normal errors are suppressed there. I've added more details in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` comes from the typo in your function name. When Vim evaluates the `'foldtext'` function, it apparently suppresses errors (which would overwhelm the editor), so that undefined function `subsitute()` returns the default value `0`.

Additionally, (though it doesn't cause harm here), you should *escape* the `.` in the *pattern*, as this specifies a regular expression, not literal text; either escape them individually (`{ \.\.\.`), or by switching to *very nomagic*:

```
let edited_line = substitute(first_line, "\V{ ...", "{ ... }", "")
```

Answer (score 3):

`.` means "any character". You must escape it to match an actual `.`:

```
let edited_line = substitute(first_line, "{ \.\.\.", "{ ... }", "")
```

Note that you could avoid that substitution with something like:

```
return getline(v:foldstart) . " ... }" . repeat(" ", width)
```

Comment: This is a good point, and I’ve updated my code to be more specific by escaping the `.`s. However, Ingo Karkat has spotted the actual problem which was a typo on my part. Whoops.

Comment: Actually since these are double quotes, don't you need to also escape the '\' characters you added (`"{ \\.\\.\\."`)? Or just use single quotes, `'{ \.\.\.'`